# order which we add elements to field extension doesn't matter

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

Suppose I am given a field $F$. Suppose also we have $a, b$ which are algebraic over $F$. In every book I have read, it was written that it is trivial to show that $F(a)(b)=F(b)(a)$. I tried to prove this equality algebraically using ring homomorphism but could not. How is this equality is usually shown?

Comment: $F[a]$ is the smallest ring containing $F$ and $a$, no?

Comment: Yes but here since we are talking about some abstract $a$ so $F(a)$ is actually the quotient $F[x]\over <f>$.where $f$ is the irreducible polynomial which $a$ is its root

Comment: Yes, but you still have $$F(a) = F[a] = \{ Q \pmod f  \mid Q \in F[X]\} =  \{u_na^n+\dots+u_1a+u_0 \mid u_i \in F\}$$ where $n=deg(f)-1$ and $a=X \pmod f$.

Comment: @User666x: The statement doesn't make sense if you are talking about "some abstract $a$".  What would it mean to say that $F(a)(b)=F(b)(a)$?  What does $F(a)(b)$ even mean?  What if the polynomial you intended to have as the minimal polynomial of $b$ becomes reducible over $F(a)$?  Talking about field extensions like $F(a)(b)$ or $F(b)(a)$ only makes sense when you already have some larger field containing both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $a$ and $b$ are algebraic is irrelevant.  We have a field $K$ with a subfield $F\subseteq K$ and two elements $a,b\in K$, and wish to show that $F(a)(b)=F(b)(a)$.  By definition, $F(a)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $F$ and $a$.  By definition again, $F(a)(b)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $F(a)$ and $b$.  Since a subfield of $K$ contains $F(a)$ iff it contains both $F$ and $a$, $F(a)(b)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $F$, $a$, and $b$.

Similarly, $F(b)(a)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $F$, $b$, and $a$.  Since "and" is commutative (that is, a subfield of $K$ contains $b$ and $a$ iff it contains $a$ and $b$), this is the same thing as $F(a)(b)$.

Comment: Nobody said we know what that field $K$ is

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are just symbols. Where did you bring this field $K$ from?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are "just symbols", then what on earth does $F(a)(b)$ mean?

Comment: We can build them abstractly using homomorphisms and quotient rings

Comment: You need to state precisely what your definition of $F(a)(b)$ is then.  There is no standard definition of $F(a)(b)$ when $a$ and $b$ are not elements of a single field containing $F$....

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove it for rings first, namely $F[a][b]=F[b][a]$. Then use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are algebraic over $F$.

Answer (score 0):

we can use the theorem:

> *Theorem:* Let be $K$ is extension field of $k$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n \in K$ algebraic over $k$ and $\sigma\in S_n$ then:
>
> $$k(\alpha_1)(\alpha_2)...(\alpha_n)=k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)= k(\alpha_{\sigma(1)},\alpha_{\sigma(2)},...,\alpha_{\sigma(n)})=k(\alpha_{\sigma(1)})(\alpha_{\sigma(2)})...(\alpha_{\sigma(n)})$$

Comment: Your "other way" is wrong: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2) \neq \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2) =\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$.

Comment: ok, thank you very much ''Waston'', I edit the answer.